# Android: Animating Images?

Tags: android, animation, imageview

I have a bar with several ImageViews, each of them is used as a button (by using the OnClickListener). Now what I want to achieve is when a user pressed the image, some kind of a glow effect will appear around the image (much like when you press barButton on the iphone).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible. The correct way to achieve this is to define a [StateList Drawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList).
The statelist defines a separate drawable for each state.

For example the following xml defines a drawable that shows the blue_button_pressed drawable if the button is pressed and the blue_button_active drawable in all other cases.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <item
  android:state_pressed="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/blue_button_pressed"/>

 <item
  android:drawable="@drawable/blue_button_active"/>

</selector>
```

You put this file in the drawable folder like any other image and also reference it in the layout files like any other drawable.

Comment: Ok, but this means I will have to create 2 images manually. Isn't there a built in animation out there?

Comment: there is no built in animation for this. above stated suggestion is the best way to implement this as far as i know

Answer (score 0):

Most Views don't actually animate animatable Drawables though, for some reason. To do this, you have to manually start the animation by calling the `start()` method on the `AnimationDrawable` (or `Animatable`, for that matter).

You can't do this immediately after setting the `Drawable` to a `View` though, for some weird reason. Instead, you can try to post the start call to a Handler, so that there is some time between the initial setting of the `Drawable` and the start of its animation.

Didn't have time to find out why it behaves like this yet, but it is what I ended up having to do.

Answer (score -1):

You could manually generate this glow effect as a background picture and make it appear as a parent view behind the actual images when clicked. But I don't think there is any native function for that.